# adding listener to div tag to watching innerHtml content

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I have a div tag and i'm changing its innerHtml attribute. And i want to add listener to this div tag to show/hide when its innerHtml changed.

Comment: If *you're* the one changing the `innerHTML` then surely *you* can just apply the show/hide effect when changing it. There's no need for an event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setInterval`](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/) to check the contents periodically, and act accordingly, for example:

```
function innerHTMLChanged() {
    if$("#myDiv").html() != "Some HTML for comparison, perhaps the previous state?") {
        $("#myDiv").hide();
    } else {
        $("#myDiv").show();
    }
}

// fires every half a second
setInterval(innerHTMLChanged, 500);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a "listener" for the `innerHtml` attribute. What you would do (but shouldn't) is have a timer which checks if the value has changed since the last update. Please, don't do that.

Answer (score -1):

You wan't to use an `onchange` feature. JavaScript does not yet have one built in. But there are plenty of code samples just a Google away for you to use.